# HTML automatically converts space or enter to <br> by mistake

Tags: html, tags, line

If I have a newline in my HTML, the browser automatically converts that newline to a `<br>` tag. For example:

```
<div>Hello  
world!</div>
```

Rendered as:

> Hello
>
> world!

Comment: Reformat your question plz. Cannot understand

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jr8t5dej/ you're wrong dude

Comment: Your `<a>` tags in `div.paginationControl` has `display:block`. You need to change these to `display:inline` or something similar to show them in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove below `CSS` from your style.css line number 12

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```